# Wordpress Ajax Request returns 0 in chrome, works fine in FF

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have a front-end Ajax call set up to randomize an image whenever a button is pressed. I set it up as follows:

**Functions.php**

```
define("AJAX_URL", admin_url('admin-ajax.php'));

add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "enqueue_eyewebz_scripts");
function enqueue_eyewebz_scripts() 
{
    wp_enqueue_script("jquery");
    ...
    wp_enqueue_script("root-js", JS_URL . "/root.js", array("jquery"));

    $script_params = array(
        'ajax_url'              => AJAX_URL
    );
    wp_localize_script('root-js', 'theme_vars', $script_params);
}
```

**root.js**

```
function parallax_randomize(e)
{
    var data = {
        'action':   'randomize_parallax',
        'dataType': 'json'
    };
    console.log(theme_vars.ajax_url);
    jQuery.post(theme_vars.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        var dynb = JSON.parse(response);

        jQuery('#front-location span').html(dynb.location);

        jQuery('.parallax-slider').fadeOut('fast', function () {
            jQuery('.parallax-slider').attr('src', dynb.url);
            jQuery('.parallax-slider').fadeIn('fast');
        });
    });
}
```

**Dynamic background callback**

```
class Dynb
{
    function Dynb() 
    {
        ...

        $this->set_up_ajax();

        ...
    }

    public function set_up_ajax()
    {
        add_action('wp_ajax_randomize_parallax', array($this, 'randomize_parallax'));
    }

    public function randomize_parallax()
    {
        $data = set_dynamic_background(true);
        echo json_encode($data);

        wp_die();
    }
}
new Dynb();
```

In Firefox, this works just fine, but in Chrome, my JS Ajax call returns 0. I can't for the life of me figure out what the problem is. Anyone?

Comment: The no_priv fixed it! Didn't know that function even existed! Thanks!! Add this as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: Use exist instead of  wp_die();

Comment: So what does exit() do differently than wp_die()? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sending an ajax request from the front-end, you need to include an action that has wp_ajax_nopriv_ ... (shown below) if you want this to work. If you don't add that action, users that are not logged in will not be able to call for the ajax function.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_randomize_parallax', array($this, 'randomize_parallax'));
```

Answer (score 0):

just add exit() in randomize_parallax() function,i think it will fix your issue

Comment: That didn't fix it :) it was the no_priv that fixed the issue :)